# what is the best Ubuntu option for my pc?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a pc with pentium 4, 256 mb RAM and 80 gb of harde disk. I want to install Ubuntu but I don't know which is the best option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would want [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org). It is Ubuntu, but instead of having the Unity desktop it has the Xfce desktop. That's the only difference. Run it live to see how well it works on your computer. I am using an old Dell Dimension 3000 with a Pentium 4 processor and a 40 GB hard drive right now. The only problem you might encounter is that 256 MB of RAM may not meet the system requirements. Look into it.